# wait for document.write to load print

Tags: javascript

document.write takes too long to print, and onload never fires.
How do I get the onload function to actually work?

```
                     w = window.open(window.location.href, "_blank");
                    w.document.open();
                    w.document.write(data);
                    w.onload(function () {
                        w.close();
                        w.print();
                    })
```

Comment: Move `write` after `onload`

Comment: The `document.write()` call is *synchronous*. You don't need the `.onload()` at all. Get rid of it and follow the `document.write(data)` call with `w.close()` and `w.print()`.

Answer (score 0):

try to print before closing.

```
w.onload(function () {
w.print();
w.close();
                        
})
```

you can also use a timeout like this:

```
 w.onload(function () {
setTimeout(function(){
 
 w.print();
 w.close();
                      
},3000)
                        
})
```

Comment: w.onload is a not function